# Why am I getting a default Activity not found error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have used `intent-filter` here:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <action android:name="com.example.test.testActivity"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I invalidated and restarted several times, but it failed.

I used Micer´s method to do things like this

```
android {
    ....
    ....

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/<YOUR DIRECTORY>'
    }
}
```

But it still has the error Default Activity not found

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".testActivity"></activity>/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.testActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

and  I think this maybe the source:

```
 <activity android:name=".testActivity"></activity>/>
```

error:Reports empty tag body. The validation works in XML / JSP / JSPX / HTML/ XHTML file types.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: please add full manifest and activity class

Comment: Overriding the `sourceSets` looks irrelevant to me.

Comment: Add intent filter in between of <activity> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this,

```
<activity android:name=".testActivity"></activity>/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.testActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

with this,

```
<activity android:name=".testActivity">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <action android:name="com.example.test.testActivity"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: It runs successfully! Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The `intent-filter` goes **INSIDE** your `activity` TAG to make it the default like so:

```
    <activity android:name=".testActivity">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: OMG,the solution is that simple.How stupid I am.Thanks for helping me.